# Mysql SELECT for friends system

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
conncections

id_user connectedto
    1       4
    2       4
    3       1
    1       5
```

i would like to do a `SELECT` that gives me back all the numbers that have a relation with the number 1 and the number 1 itself. Therefore `1 4 3 5` as result.

Comment: Can you format your question so that table structure was clear?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user as related
FROM connections
WHERE connectedto = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT  connectedto as related
FROM connections
WHERE id_user = 1
```

With UNION duplicate are removed